Communicate with AWS RDS database in local docker container
My question is probably a Docker networking one, but I'm not entirely sure, it may be a broader AWS question.
We are migrating a part of the company infrastructure to AWS and it's been setup by an external vendor. They have setup an MS SQL RDS server that hosts our databases on an isolated subnet. So, what we need to do is to port-forward port 1433 of the RDS server to the computer we are working from (whether it's our own laptop or a local VM). We do this by communicating with a bastion host EC2 instance (that runs on the same subnet) with the command: aws ssm start-session --region $region --target $bastionID --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost --parameters portNumber="$remoteport",localPortNumber="$localport",host="$remotehost". Then, we are able to connect to the database, by simply giving localhost:1433 as the address.
The above command is running in a terminal and times out after an hour, which is the default.
In order to test on AWS with all the cloud resources, we need to push to our private repository, on a branch that is part of a deployment/pipeline. That deployment will then compile a docker image. That docker image will be pushed to ECR (Elastic Container Registry). Then, an ECS (Elastic Container Service) will spawn a new container of the new image and then we'll be able to see if our code changes worked or not. All this is done on the development account/env.
So, the question is can we bypass this entire process, by making code changes locally (laptop, on-prem linux VM), then compiling the docker image and spawning a container that somehow 'thinks' that it is running on AWS instead of locally, so that it can communicate with the actual RDS instance? And so that we can test, as if it was really running on AWS?
I have already tried to run the port-forwarding command on my own laptop and then use localhost:1433 as the database address in the docker-compose.yml file, in the hopes that I could pass it as an environment variable, but that didn't work. My docker networking interface was set to host, which is the default I guess. I also tried with bridge, but none of them worked. Most of my attempts were on an on-prem Ubuntu VM.
Is it possible to do this? Thank you in advance for your time and any pointers.

localhost inside a container is not the same as localhost outside the container. You must use a physical network address of the machine running the container. BUT you also need to bind the local end of your tunnel to that address. You can do this with an SSH tunnel, but I have no idea if you can do it with a Session Manager tunnel. You could, I suppose, use an SSH tunnel to get to the Session Manager tunnel.

Have you tried running the port forwarding process inside the container as well?

Firstly, are you able to connect to the RDS database from MS SQL management studio in your local host system (where docker is running)?

i can suggest you the setup if you can tell me what os are you using  for  local development

Running in ECS, Docker container will be in a subnet with access to RDS subnet. Inside the Docker you need to connect to the database via RDS DNS name, not via localhost. You can find RDS DNS in AWS Console, it should look like mydb.<aws_account_id>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com.
Then how to build and test this Docker container locally?
There are two options:

Ask Vendor to setup AWS Client VPN endpoint inside the VPS. Then, after connecting to the VPN, you will be able to connect to the database via RDS DNS name. As VPN would connect you directly to the RDS subnet, without bastion host.
If a connection to the DB already works from a local laptop via Bastion host, and you can connect to DB via 127.0.0.1:1433 - then you could add to your local hosts file (in /etc/hosts) 127.0.0.1 mydb.<aws_account_id>.<aws_region>.rds.amazonaws.com. This would allow to use same RDS DNS name to connect to DB from a local laptop, and from ECS.

Also there are could be potential issues, when you can connect to DB from local (using RDS DNS), but it doesn't work from ECS. In this case:

check security groups attached to RDS subnet, and ensure that connection from ECS subnet is allowed.
check if a Network ACL is attached to RDS subnet, and ensure that connection from RDS subnet is allowed.


Generally, all is possible. But first of all: --network=host should be not the default, it breaks the concept of isolation.
Without network=host you can't run port-forward ... on your local machine and then spin up a container, which can use the forwarded port.
As already wrote in comments, localhost in your docker doesn't point to your local machine. Docker uses a isolated network and normally you have to use the ip of your docker0 network-device (e.g. 172.17.0.1).
Anyways, up to your problem: It seems to be same as Cannot connect to RDS from inside a docker container, I can from the host, and I can from a local docker container.
